# Device Registration page is broken

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

As of this manual:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/register-device-traits

Users should be able to edit and review the properties of the registered
devices, but in my account there's no such thing. The page just shows
{{$ctrl.productName}}, {{$ctrl.manufacturerName}}, etc and none are
editable.

[Device Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehMxW.png)

Is there any solution to be able to edit device traits without re-registering new device?

I've tried on another devices and browser, and the page is still not showing up properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.